Will a UK Standard Visitor visa applicant in the year 2025 get a vignette sticker visa or eVisa?
Immigrants in the UK who hold biometric residence permit (BRP) or biometric residence cards (BRC) now have to obtain an eVisa before 31 December 2024.
Does UK eVisa replace UK Standard Visitor visa vignette too?
The guidance at https://www.gov.uk/guidance/online-immigration-status-evisa says:

The documents being replaced are:

biometric residence permits (BRP)
biometric residence cards (BRC)
passport endorsements, such as indefinite leave to enter wet ink stamps
vignette stickers in passports, such as entry clearance or visa vignettes


The last item seems to imply that the eVisa could be replacing all vignette stickers including the ones provided for UK Standard Visitor visa.
But https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor/apply-standard-visitor-visa says:

You must have a passport or travel document that is valid for the whole of your stay in the UK. There must be a blank page in your passport for your Standard Visitor visa.

This seems to imply that a vignette sticker will be pasted on a blank page of the passport.
So it is not clear to me if UK eVisa is replacing the vignette sticket for UK Standard Visitor or not. Do you know if it is? Where can we find more information about it?

As discussed in the comments, https://www.gov.uk/get-access-evisa says:

You cannot get access to an eVisa if you:

have a visa for less than 6 months, such as a visitor visa


But this does not address my question. The above guidance applies to someone who might already have a UK Standard Visitor visa which allows them to stay in the UK for less than 6 months. It is clear that they cannot get an eVisa on the basis of their current UK physical visa (the vignette sticker on their passport). To apply for eVisa before 31 Dec 2024, they must already have a physical visa that allows them to stay in the UK for longer than 6 months.  But I want to know what type of visa a new UK Standard Visitor application is going to get in 2025. Will they get a vignette sticker or will they get an eVisa?

The website says `You cannot get access to an eVisa if you:
have a visa for less than 6 months, such as a visitor visa`. 6 months refers to the period you're are allowed to stay in the UK, not the visa validity period (i.e it doesn't matter whether you have 6 months or 10 years C visa)

@Dmitry I should have been clearer. It is true that someone who has a UK Standard Visitor visa that allows them to stay in the UK for a maximum of 6 months cannot replace their UK Standard Visitor visa with eVisa. To apply for eVisa before 31 Dec 2024, they must already have a physical visa that allows them to stay in the UK for longer than 6 months. But I want to know about new UK Standard Visa applications in the year 2025. They are not going to have any prior visa at all. So what visa will they get? Will they get a vignette sticker? Or will they get an eVisa?

Nothing about this has been announced. It is planned to happen eventually, but not imminently, and certainly not from the beginning of 2025.

Are eVisas replacing visa stickers for initial travel to the UK as well?


Eventually, yes, but visas stuck into passports – formally known as entry clearance vignettes – will continue to be issued beyond 2024, according to the law firm Bindmans. Broadly speaking, this means that for the time being foreign visitors to the UK will have a visa and foreign residents of the UK will have an eVisa.

https://commonslibrary.parliament.uk/research-briefings/cbp-10097/
